# analyzing time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have 2 arrays

```
a of length n
b of length m
```

Now i want to find all elements that are common to both the arrays

**Algorithm**:

Build hash map consisting of all elements of A

Now for each element x in B check if the element x is present in hashmap.

**Analyzing overall time  complexity**

- for building hashmap O(n)
- for second step complexity is O(m)

So the overall is O(m+n). Am i correct?

What is O(m+n) = ?? when m is large or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(m) + O(n) = O(m+n), if you know that m>n then O(m+n)=O(m+m)=O(m).

Note: hashes theoretically don't guarantee O(1) lookup, but practically you can count on it (= it's the average complexity, the expected runtime for a random input).

Also note, that your algo will repeatedly signal duplicated elements of b which are also present in a. If this is a problem you have to store in the hash that you already checked/printed out that element.

Answer (score 0):

*Average case* time complexity is `O(m + n)`. This is what you should consider if you are doing some implementation, since hash maps would usually not have collisions. `O(m+n) = O(max(m, n))`

However, if this is an test question, by time complexity, people mean *worst case* time complexity. Worst case time complexity is `O(mn)` since each of second steps can take `O(n)` time in worst case.